# Containers in STL C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

For 100 elements what container of these: map, set, list, vector will take the lowest space of memory? In other words when we push_back 100 elements to the container map, set, list and vector which of this will take the lowest space in memory? e.g. sizeof(int) takes 4Bytes, sizeof(short) takes 2Bytes, and the question is which of this containers take the lowest memory(the lowest cost of memory is the most important for me)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guesses?  Either set or vector.  No keys or pointers needed, just values and memory.  Set wins if there are repeats.

Comment: Are elements unique or duplicates are possible? For map, what is the key and what is the value?

Comment: Do you mean which would have more elements, or which container would have larger over head?

Comment: Well, I would suggest using vector. BTW, why using STL if you already know how many elements you have. If this is the case use simple array.

Comment: @JesusRamos: What would you suggest to do for finding how much space a container exactly has?

Comment: `top` or `htop` to find virtual memory usage

Comment: @duffymo Sets are usually implemented as a tree variant (often red black), and I can guarantee you these use pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a shrunk-to-fit `vector` will have the lowest space overhead of any sequence container since, other than a few pointers and/or counters, the only space overhead will be the space for the elements themselves (and any space used by the allocator, which will be unavoidable for the STL containers you describe).  `map`, `set`, and `list` all hold additional pointers for each element added.  (And a `map` will also need to hold a key type along with the value type.)  To be pedantic, you can't actually `push_back` into a `set` or a `map`, although you can `insert` into them.

On the other hand, a `vector` that is not shrunk-to-fit will commonly be over-allocated typically around 1.5, but potentially up to 2 times (possibly more, for some implementations) the required space, in order to amortize the cost of appending to it, while node-based containers like `list`, `set`, or `map` usually won't be.

If this is a concern, you might consider `deque`, which has some per unit overhead (typically much less than one pointer per element), but has a much tighter bound on its over-allocation, which won't grow linearly with the size of the sequence.

However, the space overhead of a container is not typically the primary criterion used to decide between containers such as `vector`, `set`, `list`, or `map`.  The requirements of the usage pattern are often more significant.  For example, do you need to be able to remove arbitrary elements in constant time, or without invalidating iterators or references?  If so, `vector` is inappropriate.  Do you need to be able to insert/append without invalidating iterators or references?  If so, `vector` is inappropriate.  Do you need efficient look-up (especially intermingled with insertions and deletions)?  If so, `list` is inappropriate, and `vector` is probably inappropriate as well, unless re-sorting the sequence is viable for your usage pattern.  Do you need control over the ordering of the sequence?  If so, `map` and `set` will reorder elements for you and are probably inappropriate.